# Getting the correct answer using radiobutton - Online Quiz

Tags: php, jquery

I'm doing a Online Quiz using php and I want to get the correct answer id if the radio button is checked and also I have a dynamic textbox which are the options in question. Here's the sample photo

[image]
In my database, I have a two tables which are the **e_question** and **e_answer**. This program can perform a insert query into question and answers table but I need to update the question table to insert the correct answer. Here's my sample table:

**e_question** and **e_answer** Table

[image]

The value of answer_id is 0 because I can't get the id of correct answer.

[image]
Here's my design code:

```
  <div id="container">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="control-label col-sm-2">Answer options :</label>
      <div class="col-sm-2" style="margin-right: -120px;">
       <input type="radio" name="correct" style="display: inline; position: absolute; margin-top: 10px;">
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-8" >
       <input type="text" class="form-control" name="ans[]" placeholder="Answer">
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="control-label col-sm-2"></label>
      <div class="col-sm-2" style="margin-right: -120px;">
       <input type="radio" name="correct" style="display: inline; position: absolute; margin-top: 10px;">
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-8" >
       <input type="text" class="form-control" name="ans[]" placeholder="Answer">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-sm-2"></label>
    <div class="col-sm-6" >
      <a href="#" id="add"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-md fa-plus-circle"></i> Add answer option</a>
    </div>
  </div>
```

And my jquery for dynamic textbox

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
    var addOption = '<div><div class="form-group"><label class="control-label col-sm-2"></label><div class="col-sm-2" style="margin-right: -120px;"><input type="radio" name="correct" style="display: inline; position: absolute; margin-top: 10px;"></div><div class="col-sm-8" ><input type="text" class="form-control" name="ans[]" placeholder="Answer"></div><a href="#" id="remove"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-md fa-close" style="color:red" ></i></a></div></div>';

    var maxRows = 3;
    var x = 1;

      $("#add").click(function(e){
        if (x <= maxRows) {
          $("#container").append(addOption);
          x++;
        }
      });

      $("#container").on('click','#remove', function(e){
          $(this).parent('div').remove();
          x--;
      });

  });
</script>
```

Please help me. Thank you in advance!

Comment: surely you know what the correct answer is when submitting the form? If the correct answer is always the first one in the above form you would know at submission what to insert?? However - what is the actual question?

Comment: Sir I can't get the logic on how to get the correct answer by using radio button. In my php code I insert the first question table but the answer_id is empty then second I insert the answer table. Now, both question and answer are stored into the database and I wan't to update the answer_id from question table wherein the radiobutton is checked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `e_answer` table you have add one more column like correct answer `correct_answer` (enum - 0,1).

Because database should be aware about correct answer. 
So, What will happen?

Suppose Our e_answer table like below:

```
answerid (13, 14, 15, 16)
questionId(10, 10, 10, 10)
Option (demo1, demo2, demo3, demo4)
correct_answer (0,0,1,0)
```

That means, In question no. 10 has 4 options and "Demo3" is correct answer because we have added '1' for that options.

So, we can check like, If user will choose `demo3` then it will be correct answer.

Thanks.

Comment: Thank you for suggestion but how can I validate if the demo 3 radiobutton is checked?

Comment: You can validate using Ajax. You can pass parameter in ajax and they will return you result, if it will correct then you will get true boolean.

Comment: Sir can you provide a sample code? Just for reference. I'm not too good in programming. Thank you sir

Comment: Use reference: https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-pass-a-value-to-a-PHP-script-using-AJAX

Comment: how the code know that the demo 3 is the correct answer?

Comment: You will pass selected parameters in code and that parameter we will check in db. If both will be match then it is correct answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178105/discussion-between-kiran-malvi-and-yad-young).